# is there a reason why does same output when i delete the "if (!context.canceled)" condition

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

im just curious how does same result condition "(!context.canceled)" was deleted?

```
   private void ChangeVectorDir(UnityEngine.InputSystem.InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        //if (!context.canceled)
        //{
            dir = context.ReadValue<Vector3>();
            Debug.Log(dir);
       // }
    }
```

Comment: `context.canceled` is false almost all the time. It is called based on Action Types and Interactions configuration. This is a helpful link: https://forum.unity.com/threads/learning-new-inputsystem-when-and-how-is-the-cancelled-callback-used.969501/